# How to run a PHP script in every minute from c-panel?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have created the program to read unseen emails and for sending OTP via message using some API and created cron job from cpanel but there is one option that in every five minutes (every five minutes is the least time which I seen from the option), I need to execute this in every once in a minute, because it contains OTP. Does anyone know any other alternative method to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you can use AWS Lambda service for this

Comment: Why does this need to be a Cron at all ? Why not send the message directly instead of writing details elsewhere to be picked up by your current job

Comment: +1 for @exussum suggestion. Unless there's a problem of timeout in sending the email directly when the user makes the action, that's the way to go. Alternatively you can make a daemon, basically just a `while (true) {sleep(60);}` with your php script running forever and checking every minute.

Comment: @exussum This program is for one of our clients, they already have got mails, so they approach us to implement this also, send that OTP through message.

Comment: @Andrea Olivato can you please suggest some links for reference, because I don't know much about this daemon and Cpanel. Thanks in advance.